# Why can I use square brackets to refer to both column labels and row indices when using a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`df`) with dates as index and column labels. I am able to get a slice of the dataframe by using `df['2008':]` to refer to the index, but I always assumed that you had to specify the columns first, e.g. `df[:]['2008':]`, and I just want to understand why this is the case? Wouldnt that possibly cause issues when referring to indices or columns with the same name?

Comment: It would be good if you can provide an example to clarify you query.

Comment: You specify the rows first. Also you could take a look at the `.loc[]` and `.iloc[]` of a pd.dataframe ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html))

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, let's create a simple DataFrame to do some experiments:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'2008': [1, 3], 'column 2': [2, 4]}, 
                  index = ['2007', '2008'])
df
```

```py
        2008    column 2
2007    1       2
2008    3       4
```

As you say, a common way to select a column is to index its name in square brackets:

```py
df['2008']
```

```py
2007    1
2008    3
Name: 2008, dtype: int64
```

So this works even if there is an index value of the same name. What about your way of selecting certain rows?

```py
df['2008':]
```

```py
        2008    column 2
2008    3       4
```

This also still works! Can we slice columns in the same way?

```py
df['column 2':]
```

```py
    2008    column 2
```

No, pandas still assumes we want to slice certain rows, se we get an empty DataFrame, as the index `'column 2'` does not exist.

**Conclusion:** If you provide a single index in square brackets, pandas assumes it's a column name. But if you provide a single slicing operation in square brackets, pandas assumes you want to slice the index (i.e. select certain rows). This makes sense, because slicing is more natural on the index than on the column names.

Still, this can be confusing and is not very readable, so I would recommend to use `loc` to explicitly give both the row and the column slicing for such operations:

```py
df.loc['2008':, :]
```

```py
        2008    column 2
2008    3       4
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The form

   ```
   df[something]
   ```

   determines

   1. *a series* (from a *column*), if *something* is a *name of a column,*
   2. *a dataframe* (of selected *columns*), if *something* is a *list of column names,* or
   3. *a dataframe* of selected *rows*, if *something* is a *list or a series of `True` / `False` values.*

   Examples:

   1. `df["column1"]`
   2. `df[["column1", "column5"]]`
   3. `df[[True, False, True]]     # assuming your dataframe has exactly 3 rows`
2. The form

   ```
   df[row(s), column(s)]
   ```

   (so `row(s)` are first, `column(s)` are second)
   select a cell(s) in intersection of *row(s)* and *col(s)*.

   To be safe, instead of this form use the explicit form

   ```
   df.loc[row(s), column(s)]
   ```

   to determine `row(s)` and `col(s)` by their *labels* (as opposite to their zero-based *order numbers*).